# Anyone with gout got off of alloupurinol?

Tags: arthritis

Gout is caused due to the crystalization of high uric acid and the body no being able to eliminate it ( mostly it comes at old age ).
Alloupurinol is a wonderful drug that helps but its a longterm medication for gout.
I want to know what steps can be taken to get off of its dependency ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Did you do any research about this? Can you share it (summarize what you understand to be the possibilities/reasons) with us, so we know how to best answer your question? Thanks, and again, welcome!